# At what point in the component lifecycle does a prop get injected into a component?

Tags: vue.js

I have a Parent component that is passing an array, let's call it 'bucket' that contains a bunch of stuff, to a Child component.

In my parent component, I have the following:

```
<child-component 
  :bucket=bucket
></childcomponent>
```

In my child component, I have a props section, that accepts a prop called bucket, and has it defined as an array, like so:

```
props: {
  bucket: Array
}
```

Now in the mounted section of my child component, I want to take this bucket of stuff, and do something with it. However, for some reason, it shows up as empty. So when I do this in my child component...

```
mounted() {
  console.log(this.bucket.length)
}
```

... I get a 0. When I check Vue dev tools, I can see that there are items in the bucket array in the Child component's props section. Furthermore, if in the console, with the child component set as $vm0, when I type $vm0.bucket.length, I get the correct size.

**What on Earth!?** Is the prop not injected yet when mounted is called in the Child component? If so, when does this actually happen? How do I get around this? Super confused.

Thanks!

Comment: try it on created()

Comment: First thing I tried @Badgy. Didn't make any difference.

Comment: Properties are available in the `created()` lifecycle hook. Most likely your parent component is initially providing an empty array to the child and then updating its data at some later point.

Comment: This is definitely possible. If so, how should I tackle it to run the a particular method once the prop is updated? I thought the reactive nature of the framework would automatically update subsequent values down the hierarchy when that array’s value updates.

Comment: Does your parent component initialises with an empty array(`[]`) and then after it's initialisation you push content to it?

Comment: @Giovane yes that is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to add directive v-if

```
<child-component :bucket="bucket" v-if="bucket.length"></childcomponent>
```

if you can get this.bucket.length on component mounted this time, maybe @Stephen Thomas is right.

Comment: This worked, and was the solution. Basically, what was happening was that it was passing an empty array (the initial state of the array) when the component was being called, and wasn't updating the array based on the push. However, by adding the v-if="bucket.length > 0" stipulation, it wouldn't call the component until the bucket would get populated.

Answer (score 2):

As you said in the comments, you are pushing new items to the `bucket` array.

Instead pushing items into the array, you should create a new array with the new items, example:

`this.bucket = [...this.bucket, newItem];`

Vue reactivity works when the value is changed, pushing a new item into an array is doesn't change the variable's value.

When you attribute an Object or Array to a variable, it's memory address that is given to the variable, so changing it's internal attributes or pushing new items won't change it's memory address.

Comment: This was really valuable information in guiding me to the correct solution! Thank you!